# QML Fontloader not allows to change font size

Tags: qml

I am tring to get label with my font of specific size.

```
FontLoader { id: localFont; source: ":/veranda-light.ttf"; }

Label {
  font.pointSize: 20
  font: localFont
}
```

But what I get is error on the second of `Label` description lines (`font: localFont`). I have tried to swap them without any success.

> Property has already been assigned a value.

What syntax is right for this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to follow the [documentation here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontloader.html#name-prop) and set

```
Label {
    font.family: localFont.name
    font.pixelSize: 20
}
```

If you bind `font: localFont` then you bind the property font, and can't bind parts of it again, which is, what you try with `font.pointSize: 20`

To illustrate the problem which leads to the error:

```
Text {
    text: 'text1'
    text: 'text2'
}
```

What text would you expect to be shown? Remember that QML is (mostly) *declarative* in contrast to *procedural*, so you do not define the order of execution. Only if you use *JS* you have the posiblity to do this.